# Total sum of columns of one row

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I want to add the column values in text box field  of each single row during insertion of value to that field  and display that value in a read only field.

```
HTML CODE:

    <form action="" method="post">
<table class="table-responsive">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>

                              <th style="width: 10%;">Task Name</th>
                              <th style="width: 10%;">Task Code</th>
                              <th style="width: 10%;">LDR</th>
                              <th style="width: 10%;">SDR</th>
                              <th style="width: 30%;">Total</th>
                             </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <?php
                           while($m_row = $m_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                          ?>
                          <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <?php 
                                $sqltask="SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE tasks_code='".$m_row['tcode']."'";
                                $resulttask=$conn->query($sqltask);
                                $rowtask=$resulttask->fetch_assoc();
                                ?>

                                <td><?php echo $rowtask['tasks_name'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $m_row['tcode'] ?></td>
                                <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control master" name="ldr[]" id="ldr" value="<?php echo $m_row['ldr'];?>" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control master" name="sdr[]" id="sdr" value="<?php echo $m_row['sdr'];?>" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
                                        </td>                                   
    <td>
    <input type="number" class="form-control master" id="master_diff" name="master_diff[]" readonly />      
    </td>
    <td>  <input type="hidden"  name="master[]" id="master" value="<?php echo $master_row['id'];?>" /></td></tr>
                     </tbody>
               <?php
                           }
                           ?>

               </table>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="mastertask" placeholder="Assign"/>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              </form>
```

The above code is the html code for the textbox fields where the fields ldr,sdr should be sumup for getting the total sum in master_diff field. It should be using onchange event since each entry to the textbox fields should be get added to display the final sum.

Comment: When asking questions on JavaScript behavior, it is helpful to strip down the examples to HTML & JS, leaving out any server-side scripting language (PHP in this case).
But in any case you will still have to do the work. As of now this question is too broad, as you are merely asking for a solution without having implemented any of the JS by yourself. Please try to sum those numbers and ask a narrowed question if you face problems doing so.

Comment: Can you please post the final HTML from the browser instead of PHP file?

Comment: @feeela The problem is with getting each row id for displaying the sum of each rows

Comment: @FRECEENAFRANCIS I understood, but Stackoverflow is a website for programming questions – please come up with one. “I need a solution to a problem” is not programming question… What is the exact problem? What have you tried? `onchange` is a JavaScript event, but there ain't any JS code in that example of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to remove all ids from the cycle!
Try this:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("inputs");

var summDiff = function() {
    var tr = this.closest("tr");
    var ldr = tr.getElementsByClassName("ldr")[0]
    var sdr = tr.getElementsByClassName("sdr")[0]
    var diff = tr.getElementsByClassName("master_diff")[0]
    diff.value = parseInt(ldr.value) + parseInt(sdr.value)
    
};

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', summDiff, false);
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <table class="table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Task Name</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Task Code</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">LDR</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">SDR</th>
        <th style="width: 30%;">Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>task 1</td>
        <td>0001</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control master ldr inputs" name="ldr[]" value="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control master sdr inputs" name="sdr[]" value="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
        </td>                                   
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control master master_diff" name="master_diff[]" readonly />      
        </td>
        <td>  
          <input type="hidden"  name="master[]"  value="1" />
        </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>task 2</td>
        <td>0002</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control master ldr inputs" name="ldr[]" value="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control master sdr inputs" name="sdr[]" value="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
        </td>                                   
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control master master_diff" name="master_diff[]" readonly />      
        </td>
        <td>  
          <input type="hidden"  name="master[]"  value="2" />
        </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>task 3</td>
        <td>0003</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control master ldr inputs" name="ldr[]" value="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control master sdr inputs" name="sdr[]" value="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
        </td>                                   
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control master master_diff" name="master_diff[]" readonly />      
        </td>
        <td>  
          <input type="hidden"  name="master[]"  value="3" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="mastertask" placeholder="Assign"/>
  </div>
</form>
```